# Passing a class type as a variable in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

It is possible to pass a class type as a variable in Dart ?

I am trying to do something as follows:

```dart
class Dodo
{
  void hello() {
    print("hello dodo");
  }
}

void main() {

var a = Dodo;
var b = new a();
b.hello();

}
```

in python similar code would work just fine. In Dart I get an error at `new a()` complaining that `a` is not a type.

Is is possible to use class objects as variables ?
If not, what is the recommended work around ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the mirrors api:

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class Dodo {
  void hello() {
    print("hello dodo");
  }
}

void main() {
  var dodo = reflectClass(Dodo);

  var b = dodo.newInstance(new Symbol(''), []).reflectee;
  b.hello();
}
```

Maybe it can be written more compact, especially the `new Symbol('')`  expression.

Comment: am triying to use text as the class name, think this should not work, how could i do it?

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer does not work with Flutter (because `import 'dart:mirrors'` shows an error).

Answer (score 29):

ANother way to do it is by passing a closure rather than the class. Then you can avoid using mirrors. e.g.

```
a = () => new Dodo();
...
var dodo = a();
```

Comment: Note that such solution, while very useful, may not be so elegant in case you had many parameters to pass.

Comment: Why not? You could just do something like:


`a = (String myString) => new Dodo(myString);` and then `var dodo = a("hello");`

Comment: This is the solution that works for Flutter users. The answer of @Ozan does not.

Answer (score -3):

what you can do is :

```
const dynamic a = Dodo; // or dynamic a = Dodo;
var b = new a();
b.hello();
```

This works fine for me; enjoy!

Comment: That does NOT work.